# How to throw an Exception when List<T>.RemoveAll method Removes Nothing?

Tags: c#, list

I have the following line of code:

```
races.RemoveAll(br => RaceID == br.raceID);
```

This is meant to remove all the races in the Race List that meet this condition (Has the same RaceID), and this line of code works.

However, My question is, how do I throw an exception if NOTHING was removed?

I want to do:

```
 if (nothing is removed)
{
throw new Exception ("Nothing was removed from the list, check input");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) returns `int` value - number of elements removed by the call.

```
var elementsRemoved = races.RemoveAll(br => RaceID == br.raceID);
if (elementsRemoved == 0)
{
    throw new Exception ("Nothing was removed from the list, check input");
}
```

Comment: thanks, didn't know it returned an int counter, was going to make my own :P